# Variance partitioning with crossed and nested factors: A simulation study

Tags: mixed-model, variance, nested-models, partitioning

I'm working on a variance partitioning study, where I've simulated a dataset with crossed and nested factors. I have three predictor variables and one response variable. The first predictor is crossed with the second predictor and the third predictor is nested within the second predictor.

I've simulated the data with specific variance values for each of these predictors. However, when I fit a linear mixed model using `lmer` to extract the variance components, **the estimated SD values do not align with the ones established during the data simulation**. I've tried to increase the number of groups, but this didn´t solve the issue.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
  library(lme4)
  library(ggplot2)
  set.seed(1)

# Set up parameters for simulation
  SD1 <- 4 ; SD2 <- 3 ; SD3 <- 2  # Standard deviations
  SDResidual <- 1

  G1 <- 5  ; G2 <- 5 ; G3 <- 5  # Number of levels for each predictor
  n <- 5# Sample size per combination
  N <- G1 * G2 * G3 * n # Total number of observations

# Simulating the dataset
  U1 <- rnorm(G1, mean = 0, sd = SD1)
  U2 <- rnorm(G2, mean = 0, sd = SD2)
  data <- data.frame(
    X1 = factor(rep(1:G1, each = n * G2 * G3)),
    X2 = factor(rep(rep(1:G2, each = G3), times = G1)),
    X3 = factor(rep(1:G3, times = n * G1 * G2))
  )
  data$U1 <- U1[data$X1]
  data$U2 <- U2[data$X2]
  data$U3 <- rnorm(N, data$U2, SD3)
  data$Y <- data$U1 + data$U2 + data$U3 + rnorm(N, 0, SDResidual)
  str(data)
  head(data)
  windows(15,5)
  ggplot(data, aes(x = X3, y = Y, color = X2)) +
    facet_grid(.~X1,labeller = labeller(X1 = label_both)) +
    geom_boxplot(coef = NULL) + theme_bw()

  # Fit a linear mixed-effects model using the lmer function
  LM <- lmer(Y ~ 1 + (1|X1) + (1|X2/X3), data = data)
  summary(LM)


Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Y ~ 1 + (1 | X1) + (1 | X2/X3)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 2833.4

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.81060 -0.73302 -0.04773  0.64693  2.60826 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 X3:X2    (Intercept)  0.02448 0.1565  
 X2       (Intercept) 16.09157 4.0114  
 X1       (Intercept) 13.93869 3.7335  
 Residual              5.01677 2.2398  
Number of obs: 625, groups:  X3:X2, 25; X2, 5; X1, 5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    1.299      2.453    0.53
```

[image]

Comment: Try upping the sample size of the grouping factors by a factor of 10. See if that gets you closer to the specified population values.

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you for your reply. I tried to increase the number of groups and the results did not get closer to population values. There are some tries where I got warnings of singular fit. I believe the issue may be in the creation of the dataset.

Comment: Have you tried simulating data with the `simulate.merMod()` function? First construct the design matrix `data` as before. Then (sorry for the long code snippet), simulate Y with: `simulate( ~  1 + (1 | X1) + (1 | X2 / X3), newdata = data, newparams = list( beta = c(\`(Intercept)\` = 1), theta = c(\`X1.(Intercept)\` = SD1, \`X2.(Intercept)\` = SD2, \`X3:X2.(Intercept)\` = SD3), sigma = SDResidual ) )`.

Comment: Thank you dipetkov. I made a simulation using your suggestion and posted it below. Maybe you could help me find out what's wrong with it. Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my script including the suggestion provided by dipetkov (thank you very much) and included a Bootstrap simulation to evaluate whether the standard deviation estimates were consistent with the values defined by the simulation. Attention to the standard deviation (theta) values for the random effects that need to be scaled by the residual SD.

```
  rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
  library(lme4)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(reshape2)
  set.seed(1)

# Set up parameters for simulation
  SD1 <- 8 ; SD2 <- 6 ; SD3 <- 4  # Standard deviations
  SDResidual <- 2

  G1 <- 10  ; G2 <- 10 ; G3 <- 10  # Number of levels for each predictor
  n <- 5# Sample size per combination
  N <- G1 * G2 * G3 * n # Total number of observations

# Simulating the dataset
  data <- data.frame(
    X1 = factor(rep(1:G1, each = n * G2 * G3)),
    X2 = factor(rep(rep(1:G2, each = G3), times = G1)),
    X3 = factor(rep(1:G3, times = n * G1 * G2))
  )

  Y = simulate( ~  1 + (1 | X1) + (1 | X2 / X3), 
    newdata = data, newparams = list( beta = c(`(Intercept)` = 0), 
    theta = c(`X1.(Intercept)` = SD1, `X2.(Intercept)` = SD2, 
    `X3:X2.(Intercept)` = SD3), sigma = SDResidual ) )
  data$Y = Y$sim_1
  head(data)
  str(data)

  #Parametric Bootstrap simulation
  SD.DF = NULL
  for (i in 1:50){
    Y = simulate( ~  1 + (1 | X1) + (1 | X2 / X3), 
    newdata = data, newparams = list( beta = c(`(Intercept)` = 0), 
    theta = c(`X1.(Intercept)` = SD1/SDResidual, `X2.(Intercept)` = SD2/SDResidual, 
    `X3:X2.(Intercept)` = SD3/SDResidual), sigma = SDResidual ) )
    data$Y = Y$sim_1

    LM <- lmer(Y ~ 1 + (1|X1) + (1|X2/X3), data = data)
    VARCORR. = data.frame (summary(LM)$varcor)[,5]
    SD.DF = rbind(SD.DF,VARCORR.)  
  }
  colnames(SD.DF) = data.frame(summary(LM)$varcor)$grp
  SD.DF

  DF.MELT = melt(SD.DF)
  ggplot(DF.MELT, aes(x = value)) + 
    geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(.~Var2, scale = "free_x") +
    geom_vline(data = data.frame(Var2 = colnames(SD.DF), 
                    value = c(SD3, SD2, SD1, SDResidual)),
                    aes(xintercept = value),size = 2, color = "gold") +
    theme_bw(base_size = 13)
```

[image]

Comment: I apologize, there is an error in my suggestion for how to use `simulate()`:  the theta values for the random effects are scaled by the residual SD. I've forgotten about the "scale by the residual SD" part.

Comment: Please try this instead: `theta = c(\`X1.(Intercept)\` = SD1 / SDResidual, \`X2.(Intercept)\` = SD2 / SDResidual, \`X3:X2.(Intercept)\` = SD3 / SDResidual)`.

Comment: Could you please update the answer with the correct code instructions? Many people don't read the comments. Thanks a lot. PS: Also, it's allowed to accept one's own answer.

Comment: Perfect, I just have made that! Thank you again.